# $\frac{d A}{dt}=XA-AX$

Tags: linear-algebra

$A(t)$ and $X(t)$are two matrix value functions which satisfy $\frac{d A}{dt}=XA-AX$. What can we say about $tr(A)$?

I know $tr(A)=\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_k$ but how to associate $\frac{d A}{dt}$ with eigenvalues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writing $A(t)=[a_{ij}(t)]_{i,j}$, we see that
$$\frac{d}{dt}\mathrm{tr}(A(t))=\frac{d}{dt}\sum_ia_{ii}(t)=\sum_ia_{ii}^{\prime}(t)=\mathrm{tr}\Big(\frac{dA}{dt}\Big)$$

Moreover,
$$\mathrm{tr}\Big(\frac{dA}{dt}\Big)=\mathrm{tr}(AX)-\mathrm{tr}(XA)=0 $$
so it follows that $\mathrm{tr}(A(t))$ is constant.